# Is there an event that tells you when window.outerWidth has become an accurate value?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, chrome-for-android

On Android Chrome, when a new tab is opened and you navigate to a URL, or when you zoom into a page then navigate to a new URL, `window.outerWidth` and occasionally (`document.documentElement.clientWidth`) do not always have an accurate values. After up to 3 seconds they acquire the accurate value. Is there a corresponding event from the window or DOM that I can listen for to detect this moment, or do I have to rely on a loop?

Here is a demonstration of the problem:  http://betterstatistics.org/tests/load.html
I have only seen this on Android Chrome, perhaps it is a bug?

Here is the output I get from that page when the behavior is present. Note that `window.outerWidth` (OW) is equal to 0 until 1100ms:

```
body onload()
-0ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-100ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-200ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-300ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-400ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-500ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-600ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-700ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-800ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-900ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-1000ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 0
-1100ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 384
-1200ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 384
-1300ms CW: 980 IW: 980 OW: 384
```

Here is the HTML for the test page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  var count = 0;
  var interval = 100;
  function init(){
    log("body onload()");
    outputStats();
  }
  function outputStats() {
    log("-" + (count * interval) + "ms  CW: " + 
    document.documentElement.clientWidth+"  IW: "+window.innerWidth+"  OW: " +window.outerWidth);
    count++
    if(count < 50){
      setTimeout(outputStats, interval);
    }
  }
  function log(t){
    var logDiv = document.getElementById("content");
    var tDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t));
    logDiv.appendChild(tDiv);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="font-family:sans-serif;">
  <div id="content">
    Using Android Chrome: open this page in a new tab, or go to another web page then scale it up, and navigate to this page. The window.outerWidth does not show the correct value for up to a few seconds.<br/>
    <br/>
    CW: document.documentElement.clientWidth<br/>
    IW: window.innerWidth<br/>
    OW: window.outerWidth<br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```